# Rpl-udp with simple energest contiki

Tags: contiki, cooja

I want to monitor energy for the rpl udp example in contiki using simple-energest. What do i have to write in the makefile in order for that to happen? i have tried numerous commands like 
MODULES+=os/services/simpe-energest but they don't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

To use the energest module, simply add to the Makefile:

```
MODULES+=os/services/simple-energest
```

Then rebuild the application; remember to `make clean` first. Energest will be printing the stats periodically:

```
13:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: Energest  ] --- Period summary #12 (60 seconds)
13:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: Energest  ] Total time  :   60000000
13:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: Energest  ] CPU         :   60000000/  60000000 (69 permil)
13:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: Energest  ] LPM         :          0/  60000000 (0 permil)
13:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: Energest  ] Deep LPM    :          0/  60000000 (0 permil)
13:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: Energest  ] Radio Tx    :          0/  60000000 (0 permil)
13:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: Energest  ] Radio Rx    :          0/  60000000 (0 permil)
13:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: Energest  ] Radio total :          0/  60000000 (0 permil)
```

See the [Energest documentation](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Documentation:-Energest) for details.